# How many three-character initials are possible using upper-case letters, a space, and four punctuation marks?

Tags: combinatorics

> When a new high score is achieved in in a classic video game, the player is given the option to enter three initials on the leaderboard. The three initials can be any letter ( capital only), a space, and any of these punctuation marks : period, comma, colon, hyphen. the player may repeat any initial space or punctuation mark. how many initials are possible?

I believe since the order doesn't matter, I would set this up as combination? I'm not confident on how to find the solution for this homework problem

Comment: There are $26 + 1 + 4 = 31$ possible characters and there are $3$ spots. You have $31$ possibilities to choose the first one. Then $31$ possibilities to choose the second and then and again $31$ for the third. All of that independently. Can you conclude ?
Note that the order matters since $ABC$ is not the same player as $CBA$ !

Comment: Thank you for the response. I believe I would set it  3P31 ?

Comment: Precisely you have $31 \cdot 31 \cdot 31= 31^3$.

Comment: I came up with 29791. Hows that sound?

Answer (score 1):

Short Answer:
Your answer is correct. In general, permutations are used when order does matter, and combinations are used when order doesn't matter. However, people still often confuse permutation and combinations while knowing this.

In your problem, the order does matter. For example, ABC is certainly different than CBA. Additionally, repetition is allowed in your problem. You can have the initials, AAB or AAA. Therefore, you can use the formula for permutations with repetition where $n$ is the number of things to choose from and $r$ is how many we choose. This is given by

$$n^r = 31^3 = 29791$$

Long Answer: Regardless, I think it is not necessarily helpful to just look up equations. It is more useful to attempt to derive the equation that you need for your problem. For example, you know you have $31$ things, so you know there are $31$ different ways to choose the first character.

What about the second character? Well, for each option for the first character, there are $31$ ways for you to choose the second character. This is equivalent to $31 \times 31$, or you may think of it as $31 + 31 + 31 \cdots$ up to $31$ additions.

Now, what about the third character? Well, this is similar as before, we have $31 \times 31$ options for the first two characters as we just worked out. For each of these options, we have $31$ options for the third character. Therefore, we have $31 \times 31 \times 31$, or can think of it as $(31 \times 31) + (31 \times 31) \cdots$ up to $31$ additions.